# Laravel 5 - Find Fields on "MorphOne" Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm quite new to Laravel and I'm now facing this issue while trying to create a query:

I have the following Morphable classes:

**\App\User**

```
class User {

    public function userable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

**\App\Distributor**

```
class Distributor {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\User', 'userable');
    }

}
```

- **user** table has the fields: **name**, **email**, **status**, **userable_type** and **userable_id**.
- **distributor** table has the fields: **store_code** and **location_id**.

**By using Eloquent**, i need to start the query from Distributor model and select only the following fields: 'name, email, store_code'.

I'm trying the following, but laravel says **user.name** doesn't exists :(

```
$queryBuilder = \App\Distributor::has('user');
$queryBuilder->select(['user.name']);
$queryBuilder->get();
```

> QueryException in Connection.php line 651:
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.name' in 'field list' (SQL: select `user`.`name` from `distributor` where (select count(*) from `user` where `user`.`userable_id` = `distributor`.`id` and `user`.`userable_type` = App\Distributor and `user`.`deleted_at` is null) >= 1)

I was able to achieve my goal forcing the join relationship, but this seems wrong, I think Eloquent is able to find the relation by itself as the Morph relationship is specified in the Model.

Just for record, this works good:

```
$queryBuilder = \App\Distributor::has('user');
$queryBuilder->join('user', function($join) {

    $join->on('userable_id', '=', 'distributor.id')
         ->where('userable_type', '=', \App\Distributor::class);
});
$queryBuilder->select(['user.name']);
$queryBuilder->get();
```

Also, since its a one-to-one like relationship, sometimes I'll need to order the results using one of the users columns

But I need another way to do it without forcing the join, something clean as the first example.

Comment: Have you tried starting with \App\Distributor::user(); ? I have not used morphOne, but other relationships types would return a Builder when called as a function.

Comment: @mcarson Yes, the `::user()` starts the query from users table, it just ignores the existence of `distributor` :(

Answer (score 0):

read about with() function in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)

```
$queryBuilder->select('id','store_code');
$queryBuilder = \App\Distributor::with(['user'=>function($query){
  $query->select('id','name','email')
}]);
$queryBuilder->has('user');
$queryBuilder->get();
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll try that, but how can I handle custom/dinamic conditions for users table since the `$query` for users is inside a `Closure`? The `use` statement would be a good practice? The business logic would end up inside the `Closure`, i guess.

Comment: Also, since its kind of a one-to-one relationship, sometimes I'll need to order the results using one of the users columns.

Comment: can you give examples? it's hard for me to understand, the with() function is used to eager load the relations so if it's limits you, you don't must to use it